# If functions are objects, where does the function's body go?

Tags: javascript

**If functions are objects, where does the function's body go?**

Let me clarify what I am confused about. Functions are objects, okay. I can think of an object as a hash map consisting of string keys and arbitrarily typed values. I can do this:

```
function Square(size) {
    Rectangle.call(this, size, size);
}
Square.prototype = new Rectangle();
```

I just treated `Square` like a regular object and messed with its `prototype` property by assigning a new value to it. However, if functions are just objects (or hash maps for that matter), where is the function's body (in this example `Rectangle.call(this, size, size);`) being stored?

I figured it must be stored as the value of some property, something like the following maybe:

```
console.log(Square.executableBody); // "Rectangle.call(this, size, size);"
```

Obviously, this is not the case. Interestingly, while reading "The Principles of Object-Oriented JavaScript" by Nicholas C. Zakas, I stumbled upon this:

> [...] functions are actually objects in JavaScript. The defining characteristic of a function - what distinguishes it from any other object - is the presence of an internal property named [[Call]]. Internal properties are not accessible via code [...] The [[Call]] property is unique to functions and indicates that the object can be executed.

This might be the property I was looking for above. It does not go into detail, though. Is the function's body actually stored within the `[[Call]]` property? If so, how does execution work? Unfortunately I was unable to find out more about `[[Call]]`, Google mostly came up with information on a function's `call` method...

Some clarification would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: It doesn't go into detail exactly because that's well into the realm of implementation detail; each vendor can do whatever they want as long as their implementation adheres to the "as-if" rule. The [[Call]] property is probably some kind of function pointer.

Comment: you can see the function body (usually) by calling fn.toString()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It becomes the value of another *internal property*, called `[[Code]]`:

> [**13.2 Creating Function Objects**](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2)
>   Given an optional parameter list specified by *FormalParameterList*, a body specified by [*FunctionBody*](http://es5.github.io/#x13), a Lexical Environment specified by *Scope*, and a Boolean flag *Strict*, a Function object is constructed as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> 12. Set the `[[Code]]` internal property of *F* to *FunctionBody*.

---

> If so, how does execution work?

Calling a function basically calls the internal `[[Call]]` method, which is described in http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.1. I guess the important step is:

> 3. Let *result* be the result of evaluating the *FunctionBody* that is the value of *F*'s `[[Code]]` internal property.

Comment: So the `[[Call]]` property stores a function that is being called when the original function is being called? It does not store the original function's body, though, because that's stored in `[[Code]]`, right? What kind of function does `[[Call]]` store then?

Comment: Right. The spec only defines what that function is supposed to do (§13.2.1), not *how* it is to be created. It's likely a native function written in whatever language the engine is implemented in.

Comment: @baerenfaenger It might be helpful to review the [definition of an internal property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2): "*...internal properties are not part of the ECMAScript language. They are defined by this specification purely for expository purposes. An implementation of ECMAScript must behave **as if** it produced and operated upon internal properties in the manner described here.*" (emphasis mine) What we call "internal properties" are purely notional; it is left entirely to each implementation how to actualize the behavior required of an internal property.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, for all practical purposes you can consider the function in its entirety to *be* the object. You can study the JS spec or JS engine source code to learn about how the function body is actually stored in an internal property on the object, but this won't really help you understand how it works as a JS programmer. You can see the body as a string by evaluating `fn.toString`. You cannot otherwise access the body other than to execute it or bind to it or call other methods on `Function.prototype`. However, because it's an object, it can also have properties attached to it like any other object.

Why would I want to attach a property to a function? Here is an example of a memoization function (deliberately simplified):

```
function memoize(fn) {
    var cache = {};
    function memoized(x) {
        return x in cache ? cache[x] : cache[x] = fn(x);
    };
    memoized.clear = function() { cache = {}; };
    return memoized;
 }
```

So we are placing a function `clear` as a property on the returned function. We can use this as:

```
memofied = memoize(really_long_calculation);
result = memofied(1);  // calls really_long_calculation
result = memofied(1);  // uses cached value
memofied.clear();      // clear cache        
result = memofied(1);  // calls really_long_calculation again
```

The function is enough of an object that `Object.defineProperty` can be called on it, allowing us to write the memoization function above as follows, if we really wanted to:

```
function memoize(fn) {
    var cache = {};
    return Object.defineProperty(function (x) {
        return x in cache ? cache[x] : cache[x] = fn(x);
    }, 'clear', {value: function() { cache = {}; } });
 }
```

(since `Object.defineProperty` returns the object.) This has the advantage that `clear` takes on the default non-enumerable and non-writeable properties, which seems useful.

I could even use a function as the first (prototype) argument to `Object.create`:

```
someobj = Object.create(function() { }, { prop: { value: 1 } });
```

but there's no way to call the function serving as prototype. However, its properties will be available in the prototype chain of the created object.